# Coherent photon scattering on a 2-level system: How can the commutator of the Electric field and the dipole operator be nonzero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, commutator, quantum-optics, two-level-system

Girish Argawal writes in his book [*Quantum statistical theories of spontaneous emission and their relation to other approaches*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0042382) (1974) at the end of chapter 7:

> It may appear from (7.13) that the equal-time commutation relations between the field operator and the matter operators are violated; however, there is a sense in which the commutation relations still hold.

In equation 7.13, he refers to an expression for the electric field operator at position $\vec{r}$ in the presence of a quantum mechanical dipole at position $\vec{R}$, where $S_-$ is the dipole operator:
\begin{align}
\vec{E}^{(+)}(\vec{r}, t) = \vec{E}_0^{(+)} - \frac{\omega_l^2}{c^2} \vec{n} \times (\vec{n} \times \vec{p})\frac{e^{i k_l r - i \omega_l t}}{r}e^{-ik_l \vec{n} \vec{R}} S_-\left(t-\frac{|\vec{r} - \vec{R}|}{c}\right).
\end{align}
The equation given is taken from Argawals new book, [*Quantum Optics*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107006406) (2012), 13.48, but besides being for just one system, it's the same.

Now intuitively it is clear to me that the electric field operator depends (in the Heisenberg picture) on the dipole operator, because essentially the dipole operator perturbs the electric field.
However - Didn't we in the beginning quantize the electric field especially with the assumption that its operator commutes with the operators of the atomic system, and that they are distinct degrees of freedom that can be measured at the same time? The expression for the electric field was derived by means of the Heisenberg-equation for the electric field operator. When exactly did we break the commutativity of the electric field and the atomic operators? Or how can we save it (as Argawal suggests)?

Comment: I suppose that the derivation is approximate, so the commutation relations appear to be broken up to the orders higher than the order of the terms neglected in the derivation. Otherwise, it is not clear in what sense the commutation are violated, and in which sense they hold, without having the book at hand. So you might be wasting 100 of reputation in a hope that somebody who studied from the same book answers you. Expanding a question to make it accessible to a broader audience could increase your chances of getting an answer... and might even guide you to answer it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have $[A(0),B(0)]=0$ and a Hamiltonian that mixes $A$ and $B$.
Then after evolution, both $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ are functions of $A(0)$ and $B(0)$.
Namely, not only $B(0)$ enters $A(t)$ but also $A(0)$ enters $B(t)$.
But we always have $[A(t),B(t)]=0$ which is required by the evolution equation.

That is, in addition to atom operators entering light operators, the reverse should also happen, i.e., light operators should also enter atom operators.
In such a way, miscellaneous cancellations happen to ensure the commutativity for all $t$.
Note that if you do a perturbative calculation, then the commutativity is kept order by order.
Namely, the commutator of two order-$n$ operators is an order-$(n\!+\!1)$ operator.

(Disclaimer: I'm not an expert on quantum optics. My answer just comes from general considerations.)